# WebView: Differences between LoadUrl() and LoadDataWithBaseURL()

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to **load a remote url** that haves an ad. The ad will use JavaScript.

I am using:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://myurl.com")
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Which differences will exists if I use:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://myurl.com", null, null, null, null)
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

LoadDataWithBaseURL() - Loads the given data into this WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL for the content. The base URL is used both to resolve relative URLs and when applying JavaScript's same origin policy. The historyUrl is used for the history entry.
....

LoadUrl() - Loads the given URL with the specified additional HTTP headers.

See documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: so, if it is not a string representing html code, and it is a remote url with a remote site... should i use loadUrl instead of loadDataWithBaseURL ?

Comment: Do u hv ur data locally with applied html template, css, etc??

Comment: If u r having it locally,, then use loadData() method.

Comment: Then go for loadUrl() ;